# How can I close the browser window without closing the browser?

Tags: python, webdriver

How can I close the browser window without closing the browser in webdriver? I have something like

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("http://www.google.com")
# so far so good

driver.close()
# quits the app altogether :(

driver.get("http://www.google.com")
# doesn't do anything
```

Of course I can do `driver = webdriver.Firefox()` again at this point, but is there a way to just close the window without quitting the browser? Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use `driver.get("");` instead of `driver.close();`.

Comment: I found that I can also do `driver.get("about:blank")`, not sure if they are exactly the same though.